# Error trying to connect Hibernate to Postgres

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I'm learning how to use Hibernate and I came across with a problem that I can't fix.

Error:

```
ago 06, 2018 10:59:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.4.Final}
06, 2018 10:59:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM 
org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MetaStox-DES?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true]
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 3D000
ago 06, 2018 10:59:27 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: FATAL: database "MetaStox-DES" does not exist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at jpa.ProgramaCadastrar.main(ProgramaCadastrar.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "MetaStox-DES" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2559)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:133)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:208)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
... 29 more
```

My POJO:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int quantidade;

    //Construtor
    public Produto() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }
}
```

My Execution class:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ProgramaCadastrar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sf = new 
        Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Produto produto1 = new Produto();
        produto1.setNome("Computador");
        produto1.setQuantidade(35);

        Produto produto2 = new Produto();
        produto2.setNome("Mouse");
        produto2.setQuantidade(100);

        session.save(produto1);
        session.save(produto2);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MetaStox-DES?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Re26112@</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Print executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create all database on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Annotated entity classes -->
        <mapping class="jpa.Produto"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the structure of my project on Eclipse:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just check if you are providing correct url or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

- It looks like you've left the port number off your connection URL in your Hibernate configuration file. If you're using the standard PostgreSQL port it should be something like `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<database name>`.
- Are you sure `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` is a valid option for PostgreSQL? It looks like a MySQL property.
- The comment against your Hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` says `Drop and re-create all database on startup`, but you'd need to set this to `create` rather than `update` to get this behaviour.

Comment: `createDatabaseIfNotExist` is indeed a MySQL property and not valid for Postgres. For PostgreSQL, a database must always exist for the JDBC driver to connect to it.